# OSX with Boot2Docker is not deleting files when removing images

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I removed a bunch of old images using `docker rmi` and I'm not seeing a reduction is disk space on my localdisk. Only when I destroy the boot2docker VM do I see the increase in space. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I see some reduction, but it will depend on how large those image layers are, and how much re-use of lower images you have.

it also depends on how many volumes you're using - I often forget to clean up volumes (`docker rm -v container`)